# IOS Connection failed with PushWoosh Notification

Tags: ios, pushwoosh

Till now it is working fine and we did not change our way to send the push notifications after We have lots of ios connection failed issues into the pushWoosh notification reports.
[image: PushWoosh Notification Report]

Any idea about what happens ?

Answer (score 0):

Your push certificates have been revoked. When viewing applications list in Pushwoosh you can notice red triangles on "iOS" blue symbol.

That's the reason the error you see. You need to recreate push certificates for the apps.

P.S.
I'll ask the team to provide better error descriptions for sure!

Comment: Thanks for reply, i will try.